# thumbnailImageAtTime not exact

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm trying to create an app where I have a video playing within a MPMoviePlayerController. If the video gets paused, it takes a screenshot with [thumbnailImageAtTime](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006953-CH3-SW46). The problem  is that the image MPMoviePlayerController displays after pause and the screenshot I get with thumbnailImageAtTime aren't the same.

My code looks like this:

```
[self.moviePlayer pause]
[self.moviePlayer thumbnailImageAtTime:self.moviePlayer.currentPlaybackTime timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionExact];
```

[Screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1159473/screen.jpg)

Any help is highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

What I used is `MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame`

```
- (UIImage *)imageFromMovie:(NSURL *)movieURL atTime:(NSTimeInterval)time {
    // set up the movie player
    MPMoviePlayerController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] 
                                   initWithContentURL:movieURL];
    mp.shouldAutoplay = NO;
    mp.initialPlaybackTime = time;
    mp.currentPlaybackTime = time;
    // get the thumbnail
    UIImage *thumbnail = [mp thumbnailImageAtTime:time 
                                       timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];
    // clean up the movie player
    [mp stop];
    [mp release];
    return(thumbnail);
}
```

Try this

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However I already tried the `MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame` option as well. The two frames still don't match and it looks like MPMoviePlayerController doesn't always use keyframes for pausing the video